# React js. create-react-app. Как создать несколько страниц?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, reactjs, npm

Не понимаю, как добавить вторую страничку в реакт приложение, созданное react-create-app. На данный момент в проекте есть node_modules папка, src с файлами .js и public с index.html, остальное я удалил. Мне нужно чтобы у меня было три страницы: 1)С регистрацией; 2)Со входом; 3)Список участников.
Т.е. приложение сосредоточено на работе с одной страничкой, а мне хотелось бы как-то иметь отдельные роуты(если возможно) ну или хотя бы просто переходы по кликам от одного файла js к другому.
Код index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import List from './comps/List';

class Index extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <List />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
export default Index;
```

Код index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не буду приводить полный код, просто покажу идею. 
По сути, вам для каждой вашей странички надо создать отдельный компонент. То есть компонент регистрации, компонент для входа, компонент - список участников и т.д.

После этого вы можете, например, использовать пакет [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) для навигации между компонентами. То есть, вы можете добавить в app.js

```
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

После чего поправить ваш App компонент следующим образом

```
const App = () => <div className="App">
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    </div>
  </Router>
</div>;
```

где `Home`, `Users`, `Login` - ваши компоненты. Соответственно, после этого у вас будут рендериться компоненты в соответствии с текущим урлом.

После этого вам надо будет уже добавлять возможность регистрации, аутентификации, автоматического редиректа если юзер не залогинен и прочее, но это уже отдельные вопросы, я думаю.

UPD: с некоторого времени для браузера логичнее и правильнее использовать `BrowserRouter` вместо `Router`